# Vapor How to configure request body size for an individual route

Tags: swift, backend, vapor

I am building my back-end with Vapor. And I am trying to change the default max body size for one particular route to avoid the 413 Payload Too Large error.

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/routing/#body-streaming) and tried to put:

```
app.on(.POST, "listings", body: .collect(maxSize: "1mb")) { req in
    // Handle request. 
}
```

in both

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {}
```

and

```
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {}
```

but they both throw the error
`Type '()' cannot conform to 'ResponseEncodable'`at`app`
What's the correct way of doing this? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Thanks to Leo and 0xTim's answer, I was able to resolve the above error.
However, I am still having 413 Payload Too Large error with the below code:

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {    
    try app.register(collection: ListingController())
    app.on(.POST, "api/listings", body: .collect(maxSize: "10mb"), use: ListingController.post)
}
```

```
struct ListingController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let listingRoutes = routes.grouped("api", "listings")
        listingRoutes.post(use: ListingController.post)
    }

    static func post(request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<List> {
        let data = try req.content.decode(CreateListData.self)
        let list = try List(list: data.list)
        return list(on: req.db).map { list }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many times. I finally found the right way of doing it for my situation.

```
func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
    let listingRoutes = routes.grouped("api", "listings")
    listingRoutes.on(.POST, body: .collect(maxSize: "10mb"), use: postHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to create a controller for your listing and add a static method to post it:

```
final class ListingController {
    static func post(request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<YourModel> {
        let model = try request.content.decode(YourModel.self)
        return model.create(on: request.db)
            .map { model }
    }
}
```

---

Then just pass it to the method:

```
app.on(.POST, "listings", body: .collect(maxSize: "1mb"), use: ListingController.post)
```

---

Don't forget to register your controller (RouteCollection).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am still having the 413 Payload Too Large error. I have edited the question. Could you kindly take a look?

Comment: Did you register your controller. Is it getting called? Have you tried sending less data?

Comment: Yes. Using ```app.routes.defaultMaxBodySize = "10mb"``` in ```func routes(_ app: Application) throws {} works.```

Comment: what about `.collect(maxSize: "10mb")`

Comment: Using ```app.on(.POST, body: .collect(maxSize: "10mb"), use: LogController.createHandler)```in```func routes(_ app: Application) throws {}``` does not work, 413 error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that your dummy route handler doesn't return anything. You have to return *something* in a route handler, even if it's just a HTTP status, which is the error you're seeing.

If you return a string or a model etc it will make the compiler happy.